# Using a Linux UCI Engine with a GUI (eg. Fritz 15)

Tags: engines, software, computer-chess, linux

Is there any way a Linux UCI Engine (such as StockFish 8) be used with Fritz 15? Will this involve customizing the source code and rebuilding to implement things like hash size, tablebase locations, and the like, or can those engine settings be set as BASH environment variables?

I have used a program called InBetween.exe before, to act as a conduit between the GUI and the Linux engine. However I have yet to be able to get InBetween.exe to pass  UCI environment variable commands to the engine.

If someone can post an answer to these questions, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything (possible?) for a Windows program to load an Linux executable. To me, it's impossible.

Comment: why don't you use the Windows Stockfish?

Comment: Windows uses too many resources at the best of times. I want to offload the chess engine onto a faster computer that's running linux.

Comment: so your idea is running Fritz on Linux using Wine? or maybe you're planning to run both programs on two different engines?

Comment: Have you tried using an X server on the Windows computer to display the program running on the Linux system?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it using this tool [ChessBridge](https://bitbucket.org/pokey909/chessbridge). There's also [netChess](http://home.arcor.de/bernhard.wallner/netChess.html), but the website is down, so use the [mirror at Archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20140724074729/http://home.arcor.de/bernhard.wallner/netChess.html).

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Windows and Linux for this (and this way) might not be the easiest way. Also think about future updates that can break your working solution. You already experienced this with `InBetween.exe`.

If you only use Fritz as database and to analyse your games then you might consider to use [SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) on Linux. It has Stockfish in it. Not the most recent version but you can easily install the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works fine with inbetween, for setup see:
http://rybkaforum.net/cgi-bin/rybkaforum/topic_show.pl?tid=31412